# Java Polygon2D compiler error

Tags: java

I am very new to java and I am trying to implement a polygon that can be transformed. I think this requires a Polygon2D but the following code produces a compiler error of "package Polygon2d does not exist":

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;


....


  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(theColor);
        setOpaque(true);
        int[] xs = new int[]{250,350,350,400,350,350,250};
        int[] ys = new int[]{200,200,225,175,125,150,150};
        g2.draw(new Polygon2D.Double(xs, ys, xs.length));  //error is here
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        }
....
```

Thanks all for your help and patience(hopefully!)

Comment: Can you show the entire class? Or at least the first lines...

Comment: So, what libraries are you using, as `Polygon2D` doesn't exist in the default API? (ps, you probably need to import it)

Comment: These are my imports:    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package doesn't exist. At the top of your class, there should be a package identification. If you said it correctly, it's named Polygon2d which isn't the java package in which your class, where ever this code is, exists. You need to alter it to match the correct package in which your class exists.